# Display PPA from which package will be downloaded during upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, security, ppa

I have many PPAs installed on my Trusty system. However, I feel that they might try to sneak packages into my system other than those which I include them in the first place. Technically, after adding a PPA, there's nothing preventing this PPA to try and sneak 'upgrades' for critical software into my system.

I know that I can in principle use apt-pinning to allow only certain packages to be installed via a PPA.  However, I believe this is a bit uncomfortable when there's many PPAs, and it might not always be easy to come up with rules for the pinning process.

What I'm after is a simple way to display a list of all packages which would be installed by a `apt-get upgrade` call, *and which repository they come from*; most comfortably in some table form.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe here's the answer you are looking for: http://superuser.com/q/106794. In particular, `apt-cache madison <package-name>` shows the repository/ies from which the package originates.

Comment: True, but this quickly becomes unfeasible when more than a handful of package upgrades are available.  I'm looking for a nice, table-like, easy-to-use solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call it with the `--print-uris` option:

```
apt-get upgrade --print-uris
```

It does pretty much nothing except print where it gets the packages from.

This won't work if the packages are already downloaded. The sure shot way is a dry run:

```
apt-get upgrade --dry-run -y
```

The repository label and channel should be printed along with the package.